# Is possible use multiprocessing for joining objects in python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

**I strongly suggest not to try this code** as it will open a number of blender windows out of proportion.
This is an example for illustrative purposes of what I would like to understand, that is if it is possible to speed up this operation which is very time consuming, I am trying to join certain objects, the test works well, but I currently use a processor with 8core and I am I'd like to try to understand if I can take advantage of this opportunity.

So I stop here and ask for advice, this is my wrong example:

```
import bpy,multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

##This list (joining) was created in a previous function, 
##I don't place it because the function is quite complex and not useful for my example

joining=[[#obj1,#obj2,#obj3],[#obj4,#obj5,#obj6,#obj7,#obj8],#etc...]

def join_group(joining):
    for g in joining:            
        objs = [o for o in g]
        if len(objs) > 1:
            c = {}
            c["object"] = c["active_object"] = g[0]
            c["selected_objects"] = c["selected_editable_objects"] = objs
            bpy.ops.object.join(c)

pool = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
pool.map(join_group,joining)
```